# Трудности со вводом текста в RDP-окно

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, rdp

Я использую RemoteApp (~RDP) для доступа к удалённому приложению, а далее пытаюсь симулировать нажатия клавиш. Но RDP-окно никак не реагирует на это. Если запустить удалённое приложение локально, то всё работает прекрасно! При удалённом взаимодействии - полный провал. 
Пробовал:

1. `SendKeys.SendWait(string)`
2. `keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo)*`
3. `SendInput` и надстройку над ней [InputSimulator](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)

Практически всё безрезультатно. "Практически" потому что RDP-окно всё же реагирует на

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{BACKSPACE}")
```

Но буквы и цифры ввести не получается. Операционная система Windows 7 x64 на обеих машинах, .Net версии 4.5.

У кого-нибудь есть предположение или успешный опыт, как симулировать нажатия клавиш для RDP-окна?

Comment: а как тут описано не пробовали? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138606/alternative-to-sendkeys-when-running-over-remote-desktop

Comment: Да, это пробовал (всё, кроме WCF)

Comment: а вот почему ammyy а им подобные RAdmin все работают вмодели Клиент-сервер.. т.е. RDP тебе делает канал монитора, а параллельно делай еще один канал на команды.
где-то в сети видел пример на С++, но по сути все так: клиент - сервер + параллельный сокет канал для команд..

Comment: В общем не знаю возможно, это связанно с тем, что вы отправляете команды не туда т.е. не тому окну. Нужно попробовать следующее. Делаем отдельно утилиту которая только отправляет команды в необходимые нам окна на основании HWND. Запускаем все, как есть и используем программу Spy++ она есть в VS ну или качаем ее отдельно откуда нибудь. С помощью данной программы точно определяем HWND окна которому предназначены команды и используя нашу отдельную утилиты отправляем туда любую команду. Я бы попробовал такой вариант

Answer (score 1):

Не без труда было найдено следующее решение - использование AutoIt.

1. [Скачиваете](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/) с официального сайта AutoIt, инсталлируете его;
2. Добавляете в "Ссылки" (Referenses) своего проекта библиотеку AutoItX3.Assembly.dll. Не путать с библиотеками AutoItX3.dll и AutoItX3_x64.dll, это существенно;
3. Добавляете `using AutoIt;` в начало файла, в котором будет работа с клавиатурой;
4. Для сумуляции ввода с клавиатуры используйте статический метод `AutoItX.Send(string)`;
5. В исполняемой директории программы должны лежать библиотеки AutoItX3.Assembly.dll, AutoItX3.dll и AutoItX3_x64.dll. Если вы достоверно знаете, что ваше приложение не будет запускаться на 32- или 64-разрядных операционных системах, то можете убрать одну из библиотек - AutoItX3.dll или AutoItX3_x64.dll соответственно.

Comment: Ну вот, а как же понять, что не работает(. Спасибо за подробное описание обхода подобной ситуации, может и пригодится.

Comment: NMD, непонятен вопрос. Переформулируете?